# Code signing certificate without a company

Tags: certificate, code-signing

I'm distributing an executable software that can be downloaded on my website.

So far I've been signing the executable with a company certificate (provided by Comodo) and I had thus to create a company for this purpose (I'm not making money, no accounting needed etc).

Now is yearly renewal time and I'd like to avoid the costs of maintaining this empty company structure.

Is there a way to have a certificate issues under the name of my domain name (that I own personally), without having my private name appearing anywhere (I'd like to remain anonymous)?

Many thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

To remain anonymous and still getting the certificate is against the philosophy of these certificates, IMHO.

But maybe if you create a company or a freelance bussiness with a name that matches your domain, the certificate should be named the way you want. Then, you may cancel the business, but the certificate will be issued and valid until the next renewal.

It is not nice, but could work. Also, it depends on the efforts needed for achieving this (expenses and/or time). I don't know which country you live in and what is needed to set up a new business.

Comment: Idea is that the user knows that it is legitimate code from the website they downloaded it from. Creating a company is a bit expensive (a couple of thousands of euros) and in addition certification typically require the company to be listed in an official DB (such as D&B) which costs again some money... I'd like to avoid these 5k of costs just to sign my code with a name the people with recognize

Answer (score 0):

Yes. What you need is a DV (Domain Validation) SSL certificate. What you have is an OV (Organization Validation) SSL certificate. To obtain a DV certificate the CA validates the right of applicant to use a certain domain name and no company/organization related information is verified. Refer : https://www.sslshopper.com/best-domain-validated-ssl-certificates.html

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that the DV certificates do not exist for code signing, or did I get this wrong? Thanks

Comment: Oh is it ? Then you might want to go for an "Individual Code Signing" certificate. Thwarte and Verisign provides it. Also you can take a look at startssl.com and cacert.org for cheap and free options respectively.